# what is the difference between NVIDIA RTX™ 3070 8GB GDDR6 and NVIDIA GeForce® RTX™ 3070 8GB GDDR6?

Tags: graphics-cards, nvidia

When trying to buy a laptop, I found two with different prices and only their GPU name was different.

I found these two:

- NVIDIA RTX™ 3070 8GB GDDR6 (200$ lesser)
- NVIDIA GeForce® RTX™ 3070 8GB GDDR6

What is the difference between NVIDIA RTX™ and NVIDIA GeForce® RTX™; which one is recommended to buy?

Comment: I think they are the same, just different branding

Comment: The one that says just "NVIDIA RTX" is leaving out the "GeForce" trademark and it shouldn't be written that way. They are the same brand and model of GPU, but there are many other parts in a laptop that can explain the $200 price difference.

Answer (score 4):

Geforce is simply a suffix that is not always written down, it is the same GPU though.

Do be careful when looking for laptops though. Nvidia GPU’s don't always get the same power limit, meaning two laptops with the same GPU can have significant real world speed differences, to the point where a lesser model can be faster than it's bigger brother.

I recommend looking for benchmarks and reviews of the exact laptops you are buying, to see which one is the best option.